# S2S File Transfer

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I have a use case to transfer files through a salesforce to salesforce connection. I cannot seem to find any documentation that states whether or not it is possible. I have basically looking for some direction to investigate this.

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange. Do please try to find tags specifically related to the subject of your question. It'll help attract people with the right knowledge to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit....I tried S2S and salesforcetosalesforce and could not find it. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what do you mean by Files. If attachments, then the answer is yes.

From the documentation:

> You can share attachments as child records of any supported object.
>   Attachments are automatically accepted by a connection, providing the
>   following criteria are met:
>
> ```
> The Attachment object type is published to your connection and your connection is subscribed to the object.
> The parent record for the attachment is shared with the connection.
> The attachment is not marked “Private.”
> The Share With Connections checkbox on the attachment is selected.
> The attachment is 20 MB or less.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for calling that out. I could not seem to find the right way to search for that. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can send files as a Blob via RESTful Webservice.

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lg6kQAA